# Table row shadow below all data cells

Tags: html, css, z-index, stacking-context

Im having trouble making a valid HTML table with vertical spacing between rows and shadow below each row.

The shadow always goes on top of other table data.

I have positioned the elements and set a z-index.

[image]

```css
  table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  td,
  th {
    min-width: 170px;
  }

  .shadow {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
  }

  .shadow:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #000;
  }
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>head</td>
        <td>head</td>
        <td>head</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="shadow">div</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">div</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">div</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="shadow">div</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">div</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">div</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="shadow">div</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">div</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">div</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>foot</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</main>
```

Comment: That's the problem, but what's your expected/desired result? Can you share an image, or a detailed explanation? Are the shadows to give the illusion of depth, or to create a border around the cell contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is as below, with explanatory comments in the code itself:

```css
/* removing all default padding and margins, and ensuring
   that all elements are sized to include their padding
   and border-widths: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  /* CSS custom properties for various properties to ensure
     common styling where appropriate;
      --tr-space-between is the size of the percieved/visible
     gap between adjacent rows: */
  --tr-space-between: 0.5rem;
  /* --td-padding-block is derived from the previous variable,
     using calc() so that the space between 'rows' is inserted
     as padding (padding-block) to create that row-spacing: */
  --td-padding-block: calc(var(--tr-space-between)/2);
  --shadow-color: lightgray;
  --row-color: #fff;
  /* the desired radius of the 'rows': */
  --row-radius: 0.5rem;
  /* to ensure page background can be seen (if required)
     in the row-gaps: */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* collapsing the borders between cells in order to allow the
     content to be contiguous, and using a different means to
     achieve row-"separation": */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  /* using a CSS filter, drop-shadow(), to create the shadows: */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5rem var(--shadow-color));
  /* centering the <table> */
  margin-inline: auto;
}

td,
th {
  min-width: 170px;
}

td,
th {
  /* again to ensure that the page background is - where
     appropriate - visible through the visual gaps: */
  background-color: transparent;
}

td {
  /* setting the cell padding on the block axis, to "separate"
     the "rows", while no padding is applied on the inline
     axis, so that the rows are visually contiguous: */
  padding-block: var(--td-padding-block);
}

/* using logical properties to set the border radii: */
td:first-child .content {
  border-start-start-radius: var(--row-radius);
  border-end-start-radius: var(--row-radius);
}

td:last-child .content {
  border-start-end-radius: var(--row-radius);
  border-end-end-radius: var(--row-radius);
}

.content {
  /* setting the background-color of the "row": */
  background-color: var(--row-color);
  /* applying padding on all axes, to move the content
     away from the edges of the 'row': */
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- I've changed the class-name of the <div> from 'shadow' to
           'content' to reflect what the "purpose" of the element: -->
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>foot</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</main>
```

There are, of course, other approaches; I've shown a couple more in the following example, again: explanatory comments are in the code:

```js
const changeBackground = (evt) => {
  let {
    currentTarget
  } = evt, {
    value
  } = currentTarget,
  table = document.querySelector('table');

  table.dataset.shadow = value;
}

document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(
  (el) => el.addEventListener('change', changeBackground)
);

document.querySelector('input:checked').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```css
/* removing all default padding and margins, and ensuring
   that all elements are sized to include their padding
   and border-widths: */

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* a relatively simple background to show how the transparencies
     might be beneficial; otherwise irrelevant to the demo: */
  background-image:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      to bottom left,
      transparent,
      hsl(140deg 90% 80% / 0.7)
    ), radial-gradient(
      at 0 0,
      hsl(300deg 95% 85% / 1),
      hsl(180deg 95% 85% / 1)
    );
  block-size: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;
}

form {
  inline-size: 70%;
  margin-block: 1rem;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0 none transparent;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.labelText {
  /* using a CSS custom property to simplify the CSS: */
  --active-indication: hsl(0deg 75% 70% / 0.55);
  background-color: #cccd;
  /* using a background-image to give show whether a
     selection has, or has not, been made; this is the
     default 'inactive' state: */
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
    270deg,
    var(--active-indication) 0 1.5rem,
    /* gives the illusion of a border separating the
       background-color of the element, and the
       'activation'/checked state: */
    #0009 1.5rem calc(1.5rem + 1px),
    /* transparent, to allow the background to show through: */
    transparent calc(1.5rem + 1px)
  );
  border: 1px solid #0009;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  padding-inline-end: 2rem;
}

/* moving the radio inputs off screen to hide them: */
input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2000px;
}

/* this selector matches the .labelText that immediately
   follows a checked <input>; despite being hidden off-screen
   the <input> still precedes the .labelText element in
   the DOM: */
input:checked + .labelText {
  /* here we update the custom property, which updates
     the background-image/linear-gradient: */
  --active-indication: hsl(160deg 95% 75% / 1);
}

table {
  /* CSS custom properties for various properties to ensure
     common styling where appropriate;
      --tr-space-between is the size of the percieved/visible
     gap between adjacent rows: */
  --tr-space-between: 0.5rem;
  /* --td-padding-block is derived from the previous variable,
     using calc() so that the space between 'rows' is inserted
     as padding (padding-block) to create that row-spacing: */
  --td-padding-block: calc(var(--tr-space-between)/2);
  --shadow-color: #339a;
  --row-color: #fff;
  --row-inset: 1rem;
  /* the desired radius of the 'rows': */
  --row-radius: 0.5rem;
  /* to ensure page background can be seen (if required)
     in the row-gaps: */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* collapsing the borders between cells in order to allow the
     content to be contiguous, and using a different means to
     achieve row-"separation": */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-block: 1rem;
  /* centering the <table> */
  margin-inline: auto;
}

/* using attribute-selectors along wtih custom data-* attributes
   to appropriately style the <table> based on the choice made as
   to the approach: */
table[data-shadow="drop-shadow"] {
  /* using a CSS filter, drop-shadow(), to create the shadows: */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2rem var(--shadow-color));
}

table[data-shadow="box-shadow"] {
  /* using a box-shadow, note that this provides a shadow *around*
     the element, but not between the 'rows' (this is why I didn't
     use box-shadow in the original code, and this is simply to
     illustrate that point): */
  box-shadow: 0.5rem 0.5rem 2rem var(--shadow-color);
}

table[data-shadow="backdrop-filter"] {
  /* this allows a number of different functions to be used to
     to style the view of whatever is visible "through" the
     background of the <table> element: */
  backdrop-filter: hue-rotate(245deg) opacity(0.4);
}

td,
th {
  min-width: 170px;
}

td,
th {
  /* again to ensure that the page background is - where
     appropriate - visible through the visual gaps: */
  background-color: transparent;
}

td {
  /* setting the cell padding on the block axis, to "separate"
     the "rows", while no padding is applied on the inline
     axis, so that the rows are visually contiguous: */
  padding-block: var(--td-padding-block);
}


/* using logical properties to set the border radii: */

td:first-child .content {
  border-start-start-radius: var(--row-radius);
  border-end-start-radius: var(--row-radius);
}

td:last-child .content {
  border-start-end-radius: var(--row-radius);
  border-end-end-radius: var(--row-radius);
}

td:first-child {
  padding-inline-start: var(--row-inset);
}

td:last-child {
  padding-inline-end: var(--row-inset);
}

.content {
  /* setting the background-color of the "row": */
  background-color: var(--row-color);
  /* applying padding on all axes, to move the content
     away from the edges of the 'row': */
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <form action="#" id="choices" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Choose approach</legend>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="shadowType" value="drop-shadow" checked>
        <span class="labelText"><code>filter: drop-shadow()</code></span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="shadowType" value="box-shadow" >
        <span class="labelText"><code>box-shadow</code></span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="shadowType" value="backdrop-filter" >
        <span class="labelText"><code>backdrop-filter</code></span>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- I've changed the class-name of the <div> from 'shadow' to
           'content' to reflect what the "purpose" of the element: -->
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">div</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>foot</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  
  .shadow {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
  }

  .shadow:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #000; 
    }
    
  tr:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
       cursor: pointer;
       box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       background-color: #fbfbfb;
}


td, th {
 text-align:center;
  min-width: 170px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>head</td>
        <td>head</td>
        <td>head</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="shadow">1</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">2</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">3</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="shadow">4</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">5</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">6</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="shadow">7</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">8</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">9</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>foot</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  
  .shadow {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
  }

  .shadow:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px 0px #000; 
    }
    

  
  tr:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
}


td, th {
 text-align:center;
  min-width: 170px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>head</td>
        <td>head</td>
        <td>head</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="shadow">1</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">2</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">3</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="shadow">4</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">5</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">6</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="shadow">7</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">8</div></td>
        <td><div class="shadow">9</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>foot</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</main>
```

Comment: see that approach you like it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community okay i am trying to improve it.